# UITableViewCell display under other view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I cannot convince `UITableViewCell` to display under another view as per the attached image. It happens when I embed `UITableView` into `UIViewController`.

```
VoucherTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VoucherTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[VoucherTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"VoucherTableViewCell"];
}
```

Image one is before scrolling up.

[image]

Image two is the problem.

[image]

Comment: Check your constraints and frames.

Comment: @anhtu how to check? I've already checked those.

Comment: How did you embed UITableView to UIViewController? Any code or more information? It's hard to know your problem with a little info.

Comment: @anhtu I've put UITableView in storyboard thus no resource to show code here.

Comment: "UITableViewCell display under another view". So DEALS, REDEEMED, HISTORY are in UITableView?

Comment: @anhtu nope. Those are UISegmentControl. UITableView is under this segment control.

Comment: I think problem with position of UITableView in UIViewController. It would be helpful if you could provide an image of the view controller in storyboard, so we could see view hierarchy and constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try in viewDidLoad this code

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, yourTopiew.height, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps...

```
1. Make sure you are using correct Size class for iPhone.
2. Remove your tableView constraints if any.
3. Position your tableView correctly. (Bottom of your buttons)
4. Add top,bottom, left, right constraint to tableView.
5. Also make sure your buttons have correct constraints.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the frame and positioning of your table view.

**First** the table view is places above the buttons in the view hierarchy in you nib file.

**Second** you need to set the frame and constraints of the tableview as such that it starts right from where the buttons end.